# How to INSERT simple PHP array into MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, insert, sql-insert

I have two results/outputs from a couple of scripts.

Script 1 result:

```
    print_r($unit);

OUTPUT =  

Array ( [0] => http://one.com, [1] => http://two.com, [2] => http://three.com/, )
```

Script 2 result:

```
    echo $item."<br>"; 

OUTPUT = 

http://one.com,
http://two.com,
http://three.com,
```

I'm embarrassingly failing to failing to import either one into a MySQL table which has just two fields: ID and URL.

```
//Connect to MySQL...

// Attempt insert query execution

    $list=implode($unit);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO urls (url) VALUES ('$list')";
    if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
        echo "Records added successfully.";
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($conn);
```

The insert works but the code is inserting all 3 urls into a single field:

```
id  url
1   http://one.com,http://two.com,http://three.com,
```

DESIRED MySQL table result for both script 1 and 2:

```
id  url
1   http://one.com
2   http://two.com
3   http://three.com
```

THANKS for your thoughts!

Comment: `$list=implode(",", $unit);` try that out.

Comment: @Fred-ii- : I think he wants one row for each record.

Comment: @MateoBarahona 10-4. *grazie*

Comment: @MateoBarahona 10-4 = "acknowledged". grazie = "thank you". ;-)

Comment: Yeah, one row per record. Thanks.

Comment: @Fred-ii- : oh i didn't know that (10-4) ! Thanks for teaching me :)

Comment: @MateoBarahona prego (welcome) and there you have it, your Italian lesson for the day! *(I'll bet you already knew that)* (10-4, is widely used in the services area of the world, police, army, navy, etc.) ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are doing a bit wrong here, you need to **[`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)** the `$unit` on the basis of ',' instead of **[`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)**

here it is

```
if (is_array($unit)) {
    $unit = implode(',', $unit);
} // check if array, convert to string
$list = explode(',', $unit);
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO urls(url)  VALUES (?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $url);
foreach ($list as $url) {
    if (empty($url)) {
        continue;
    }

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    echo "Records added successfully.";
}
```

Comment: [`$list=implode(",", $unit);`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33509158/how-to-insert-simple-php-array-into-mysql-table#comment54801939_33509158) I guess I meant "explode"; *my bad*.

Comment: You're not sanitizing your values. That's EXTREMELY dangerous.

Comment: yes, but OP only wants to insert at the moment(this could also be a local project) @Terry

Comment: Local project is no excuse for using sloppy code.

Comment: The explode results in "Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given..."  and the foreach line results in "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()..."

Comment: "implode — Join array elements with a string"

Comment: @Mubin -  ALMOST there!  It is now inserting the rows, but every other row is empty...umm..

Comment: This really needs `bind_param`. Using the manual escaping function is asking for trouble.

Comment: @tadman: updated, if it need bit more updation, please Edit the answer

Comment: @Mubin - that worked awesome. Thanks for the help.  I appreciate this community.   Thanks to all others for your comments too.  Cheers!